# ./node_modules/electron/index.js:1:11-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'node_modules/electron'

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I am using below for my electron/angular project, i am getting error
./node_modules/electron/index.js:1:11-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '$HOME/node_modules/electron'
Can someone please let me know which version of electron to use for not seeing this error.

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.13
Node: 16.13.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.1.0
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.13
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.13
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.13
@schematics/angular             12.2.13
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
electron     13.1.9
```

Comment: This sounds like Angular's bundler configuration not playing well with the `fs` module. I'd start by looking in there. I don't think an Electron upgrade would help.

Comment: "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server" using this builder helped to resolve.

Comment: @vrreddy1234 - I am glad you solved this, but really, saying how you solved it would be very helpful.  For instance, what settings did you use in your custom webpack to solve the problem?  I installed the package and thought I had it set properly - but apparently, yours and mine are different enough that I still get the error.